# Symfony - No route found for GET

Tags: php, symfony

No route found for "GET [http://pogodynka.localhost:46530/weather"](http://pogodynka.localhost:46530/weather%22)

This is the error I get when I try to access:

```
http://pogodynka.localhost:46530/weather
```

**config/Routes.yaml**

```
weather_in_city:
  path: /weather/{country}/{cityName}
  controller: App\Controller\WeatherController:cityAction
  requirements:
    city: \d+
```

**config/packages/Routing.yaml**

```
    router:
        utf8: true

        # Configure how to generate URLs in non-HTTP contexts, such as CLI commands.
        # See https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-commands
        #default_uri: http://localhost

when@prod:
    framework:
        router:
            strict_requirements: null
```

**src/Controller/WeatherController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Location;
use App\Repository\MeasurementRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class WeatherController extends AbstractController
{
    public function cityAction($cityName, MeasurementRepository $measurementRepository, CityRepository $cityRepository): Response
    {
        $cities = $cityRepository->findCityByName($cityName);
        $city = $cities[0];
        $measurements = $measurementRepository->findByLocation($cityName);

        return $this->render('weather/city.html.twig', [
            'location' => $city,
            'measurements' => $measurements,
        ]);
    }
}
```

[debug:router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TBP2.png)

Comment: Start with `bin/console debug:router`. Most likely you just need to supply values for country and cityName

Comment: just added screen from debug:router

Comment: [please do not post images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You should use route annotations. This way you can define the route directly in the controller class. Here is a nice write up and example: [SymfonyCasts: Annotation & Wildcard Routes](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony5/annotations)

My personal opinion but I find annotations to be the way to go.